# bash: count the number of the found filles

Tags: bash, find

my script putted into the alias looking for all the files with the extension of the parmtop or prmtop  and then print all of them with its size.

```
alias find_prmtop='find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 100 \( -type f -name ".parmtop" -o -name "*.prmtop" -o -name "*.parm7" -o -name "*.parmtop" \) -printf "%p %k KB \n"'
```

which gives me:

```
./MD_cluster10_1_300K/protein.prmtop 47360 KB 
./MD_cluster11_1_300K/protein.prmtop 47104 KB 
./MD_cluster1_1_300K/protein.prmtop 43008 KB 
./MD_cluster2_1_300K/protein.prmtop 50176 KB 
./MD_cluster3_1_300K/protein.prmtop 50176 KB 
./MD_cluster4_1_300K/protein.prmtop 39808 KB 
./MD_cluster5_1_300K/protein.prmtop 47488 KB 
./MD_cluster6_1_300K/protein.prmtop 46976 KB 
./MD_cluster8_1_300K/protein.prmtop 51072 KB 
./MD_cluster9_1_300K/protein.prmtop 48128 KB
```

how could I additionally count these filles and add at the end "The total number of the detected files is : number" ??

Comment: Save the output to a fie or variable, then use `wc -l` to count the lines

Comment: Or use a function instead of alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliasses are nice for relatively simple command substitution. If you want to do something more elaborate, you should use a function. Something like:

```
find_prmtop(){
    local tmp=$(mktemp -t hoppa.XXXXXXXX)
    find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 100 \( -type f -name ".parmtop" -o -name "*.prmtop" -o -name "*.parm7" -o -name "*.parmtop" \) -printf "%p %k KB \n" |
        tee $tmp
    echo -n "The total number of the detected files is : "
    wc -l $tmp
    rm -f $tmp
}
```

--------edit---------

This will work as long as there are no files `*.prmtop`, `*.parm7`
or `*.parmtop` with newlines in their name. Otherwise, the count may be wrong.

```
find_prmtop(){
    local tmp=$(mktemp -t hoppa.XXXXXXXX)
    find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 100 \( -type f -name ".parmtop" -o -name "*.prmtop" -o -name "*.parm7" -o -name "*.parmtop" \) -printf "%p %k KB \n"
    find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 100 \( -type f -name ".parmtop" -o -name "*.prmtop" -o -name "*.parm7" -o -name "*.parmtop" \) -ls | wc -l       
}
```

will work if you have filenames with a newline in it, but if the tree  is large, it will take more time.

Comment: ... and then this function may be used from the alias ??

Comment: @JamesStarlight the function replaces the alias; in this case the invocation of the alias and the function are the same, namely: `find_prmtop`; what you'll want to do is add the function to your `.profile` or `.bashrc`, or save in a file and have it sourced by one of these resource files

Comment: so still have not understood how to execute your function in the same manner as alias. I added it directly to the bashrc but when I tried to sorce it I got the error bash:  fin de fichier (EOF) 1: erreur de syntaxe : fin de fichier prématurée

Comment: and what is the purpose of the local tmp=$(mktemp -t hoppa.XXXXXXXX) ?

Comment: @JamesStarlight If you do not know much about bash and the common utilities, the command you should at least remember is `man`. `man mktemp`, for instance will immediately answer your question.

Comment: Assigning variables at declaration has a drawback: you cannot detect errors. It would be a bit better to first `local tmp`, and then `tmp=$(mktemp -t hoppa.XXXXXXXX) || exit 1`. Ideally you would add a trap to delete the temporary file even if an error occurs before the end of your function.

Comment: Your solution is nice but it is not robust against file names that contain newline characters. Another option would be to add `-exec bash -c "echo 1 >> $tmp" \;` to add exactly one line in the temporary file per found file.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet If I look at the sample filenames provided by the OP, I think it is highly unlikely that there is a filename with a newline. Furthermore: How often has anyone seen a normal file with a filename with a newline (dig in your long-time memory). And lastly: if there is a filename with a newline, the absolute worst that can happen is that the count will be wrong, No privilege escalation, no server downtime,. So yeah, I would think this solution is more than sufficient here.

Comment: @JamesStarlight: The function is used instead of an alias. From your interactive shell, you can use it in the same way. If you get an end-of-file error, then you are probably missing a quote or a `}`. `local tmp=$(mktemp -t hoppa.XXXXXXXX) ` declares a variable that is local to the function (local, so it will never interfere with the rest of your shell) and the content of the variable is a temporary file name provided by `mktemp`.

Comment: @LjmDullaart As usual, the question is not _what is the probability that my solution fails_. It is _how to make sure it never fails_.

Comment: Adding it to `.bashrc` and calling it fails on the single quote that should be removed: `...-printf "%p %k KB \n"` is followed by `'`.

Comment: @LjmDullaart I don't have to dig deep in my memory and I already saw bugs due to this that were extremely difficult to find. So when you have two equivalent options the question is not probabilities, it is which can go wrong and which cannot. Moreover, even if your solution will work for the OP, you don't know by who and for what purpose your answers will be used in the future...

Comment: Also try https://explainshell.com/ and see further https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Comment: Great thank you very much ! and generally the functions could be saved anywhere in the bashrc file or it'd be better to store it near other alliases ??

Comment: Anywhere in the bashrc is OK, but I would keep some kind of structure  (f.e. first all environnement variables, then all aliasses, then all functions)

Answer (score 0):

Add a function in your `.bashrc` and pipe your result through `tee` and `>()`.

```
findtop() {
  find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 100 -type f \
    \( -name ".parmtop" -o -name "*.prmtop" -o -name "*.parm7" -o -name "*.parmtop" \) \
    -printf "%p %k KB \n" | 
    tee >(wc -l | sed 's/^/Nr of lines: /')
}
```